# Python DataFrame Date Conversion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am a newbie to python. Can someone help me for an alternative to

```
ax1.plot(data['Date'].astype(datetime.datetime),data[tag +'_Open'])
ax2.bar(data['Date'].astype(datetime.datetime).values, data[tag 
+'_Volume'].values)
```

I am working in colab and it gives me the error.

```
dtype '<class 'datetime.datetime'>' not understood
```

What can I replace the astype with to get it to return datetime

Comment: what about `data['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()` ? From [this post](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25730)

Comment: Look into `pd.to_datetime`, this is not the way to convert a string to datetime format

Comment: `astype('datetime64')`?